# How to remove decimal without Changing the int value lua

Tags: lua, bytecode

I am writing a custom bytecode thing and when I am decoding it I get these .0 decimals added:

```
\114.0\101.0\113.0\117.0\105.0\114.0\101.0\
```

I have tried using math.floor and math.ceil but they change the number before the .0

So how would I go about fixing this?

My current code is:

```
local OVal = math.random(1, 999)
local SVal = math.random(1, 999)
local TVal = math.random(1, 999)

local function customEnc(STR)
local currentVar = ""
local strings = {}
STR:gsub(".", function(c)
    if c == [[\]] then
        local newVar = tonumber(currentVar)
        if newVar == nil then
        else
            newVar = newVar * OVal /SVal
            table.insert(strings, tostring(newVar))
            newVar = ""
        end
        currentVar = ""
    else
        currentVar = currentVar .. c
    end
end)
local newString = ""
for i,v in pairs(strings) do
    newString = newString .. [[\]] .. v
end
newString = newString .. [[\]]
return newString
end

local function customDec(STR)
    local currentVar = ""
    local strings = {}
    STR:gsub(".", function(c)
        if c == [[\]] then
            local newVar = tonumber(currentVar)
            if newVar == nil then
            else
                newVar = newVar / OVal *SVal
                table.insert(strings, tostring(newVar))
                newVar = ""
            end
            currentVar = ""
        else
            currentVar = currentVar .. c
        end
    end)
    local newString = ""
    for i,v in pairs(strings) do
        newString = newString .. [[\]] .. v
    end
    newString = newString .. [[\]]
    return newString
end
```

Comment: How are you producing the bytecode? and how are you decoding it?

Comment: I split it at every "\" and then make it in to a number and then multiply that number by a random value and adding a random value to that number

Comment: can you add an example of the code to your question?

Comment: Okay I will do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.format` with the format string `%.0f` to format the number to remove the unneeded decimal places:

```
for i,v in pairs(strings) do
  newString = newString .. [[\]] .. string.format("%.0f",v)
end
```

Also i would note you are using `pairs` here not `ipairs` so your order is undetermined which means you can not guarantee the process can be reversed.

Comment: Now the respnse is: \0.0\0.0\0.0\0.0\0.0\0.0\0.0\

Comment: when I run: load(customDec("\112\114\105\110\40\34\72\101\108\108\111\34\41\10")) it errors with this message: :1: unexpected symbol near '\ do you know how to fix this?

Comment: i did `print("\112\114\105\110\40\34\72\101\108\108\111\34\41\10")` and got `prin("Hello")` seems your missing a `t` I dont know where you are getting an error about the slash though... that said your message shouldn't end in a with a slash just notice you do that in your code

Comment: I added the wrong bytecode in the comment, that was for the encoding. But it errors when you do load(customDec(enc)) -- enc is a variable with the encoding for the print